# Capture output from powershell without The PowerShell object

Tags: c#, powershell

In my c# app there is some button, when the user clicks on this button the app runs a powershell script.

a window of powershell pops out and the user see the results in the power shell window.

I am trying to grab the output from the powershell window and show the output in some textbox from my app.

Here my code:

```
int ExecuteScript(string path)
        {
            // this is the script that i would run in a process and would monitor. You don't need to put anything
            // in the script just put it to sleep for like 1 minute or so.
            string command; 
            RunspaceConfiguration runspaceConfiguration = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
            Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(runspaceConfiguration);
            runspace.Open();

            RunspaceInvoke scriptInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
            scriptInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted");

            command = "$job = [Diagnostics.Process]::Start(\"powershell.exe\", \"" + path + "\")"; // * if $null is passed it needs to be '$null' *
            scriptInvoker.Invoke(command);

            int pid = 0;
            foreach (PSObject result in scriptInvoker.Invoke("$job.id"))
            {
                if (result != null)
                {

                    pid = Convert.ToInt32(result.ToString());
                }
            }
            return pid;

        }
```

For some version issues I'm not using `PowerShell` object to run the script

Comment: Since the `PowerShell` API was introduced in V2, what sort of version issues are you having? Are you running on PowerShell V1? Also, why are you using the PowerShell `Runspace` API to launch a PowerShell process? I would expect that either you'd use the `Process` class directly from C# to launch the process, or use the `Runspace` API to run the script in-process.

Answer (score 0):

When you are calling Powershell.exe you can include "-windowstyle hidden" and powershell should run in the background.